# How to verify that this is a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Let $ g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ , $ g (x, y) = (x^2-y^2, y) $ be a differentiable map. Let $ r $ the line passing through $(1, 0) $ parallel to the $ y-$axis. Prove that $ g^{-1}(r) $ is a submanifold of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $

I don't have many instruments to prove this fact, and the only theorem which involves the inverse of a differential function is this one:

> **Theorem:** Suppose $ X, Y $ are manifolds and $ f:X \to Y $ a differentiable map. Let $ y \in Y $. If $ f $ is a submersion at each point of $ f^{-1}(y) $, then $ f^{-1}(y) $ is a submanifold.

I think this is the result to use, but $ r $ is not a point of $\mathbb{R}^2 $, so I don't know whether i can use the theorem. Maybe there is something else to use, but these are my first exercises involving manifolds so I don't have much practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $r=\{(1,y)\,:\,y\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore

$$g^{-1}(r)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,g(x,y)\in r\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,x^2-y^2=1\}$$

Define $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, then $g^{-1}(r)=f^{-1}(1)$. Now check the gradient of $f$ and apply your theorem.

Comment: Very clear thanks!